# Wordpress search results

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a searchfrom.php for wordpress but then it's giving me a false returns you can try the search yourself [here](http://www.testground.idghosting.com/philcom/home/)

**Here is the code for my search form**

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/">
<input type="text" class="form-text" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars($s, 1); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" class="goField" />
</form>
```

**Here is the code of my search.php page**

```
get_header(); ?>
  <div id="BodyWrap">
<div id="mainCont">
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<div id="mainCopy">

    <div id="content" class="narrowcolumn" role="main">

    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <h2 class="pagetitle">Search Results</h2>

        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
        </div>


        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div <?php post_class() ?>>
                <h3 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <small><?php the_time('l, F jS, Y') ?></small>

                <p class="postmetadata"><?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?> Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> | <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '', ' | '); ?>  <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?></p>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
        </div>

    <?php else : ?>

        <h2 class="center">No posts found. Try a different search?</h2>
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

It does do the search but there are this "at | Uncategorized | No comment" which is not even part of the search term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I see. You want to know why it lists categories even if they don't match the search term?
Well, that's the default WordPress behavior. I guess you could change it, but I don't see why, actually.

It is the

```
Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> | <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '', ' | '); ?>  <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments »', '1 Comment »', '% Comments »'); ?>
```

part in your search.php that displays the categories and comments count. However, if you remove the code above, the categories and comments count will not be shown (even if the categories matches your search term).

You may replace the code above with this code, if you only want to display the categories if they are the same as the search term:

```
<?php
foreach(get_the_category() as $cat){
    if(strtolower($cat->cat_name)==strtolower($_GET['s'])){
        $match = true;
    }
}
if($match){ echo 'Posted in '; }
foreach(get_the_category() as $cat){
    if(strtolower($cat->cat_name)==strtolower($_GET['s'])){
        echo $cat->cat_name;
        echo ', ';
    }
}
edit_post_link('Edit', '', ' | ');
comments_popup_link('No Comments »', '1 Comment »', '% Comments »');
?>
```

It should produce something like this, if the categories match the search term:

```
Posted in Category That Matches, Edit | 1 Comment
```

If the categories don't match the term:

```
Edit | 1 Comment
```

If you don't want the comments count (or Comments Off) to display, remove the `comments_popup_link('No Comments »', '1 Comment »', '% Comments »');` line from my code.

Comment: You might want to use preg_match() instead of just checking if the category is equal to the search term.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer I really don't want to change it I just wante to know why when you do a search e.g. phil on the site it gives out blank list that says this "at | Uncategorized | No comment" please visit the site and do a search "Phil" and you will see the problem. Thank you

Comment: Actually, no. I see, for example, "Posted in Articles | No Comments »". Does the problem remain if you log out?

Comment: I mean not but how do I remove that "Posted in Uncategorized | Comments Off".. as you can see it shows up even when it is not a search term and not even an article inside it...

Answer (score 0):

> It does do the search but there are
>   this "at | Uncategorized | No comment"
>   which is not even part of the search
>   term.

You'll have to edit your page.php or single.php to exclude the search page from showing the Comments/Categories.

Comment: can you show me how this is all new to me and also not to great in PHP

Comment: After looking at your site again, looks like your using the default WordPress search function. Could you post the code to your search.php file?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change searchform.php to [this](http://pastie.org/895618)?

Comment: yes but I am trying to figure out is why does it include "Posted in Uncategorized | Comments Off" if it's not even in the search term.

Comment: Because your search results are configured to display that information. The search results are a wordpress loop like the index page.

If you don't want the into to show, remove it from the loop.

Or am I completely off target?

Comment: yes but if I remove it in the loop it ould show up empty divs.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line that's wrapped in

. That will get rid of the "Posted in Uncategorized | Comments Off".

The reason it show's is because it is the meta information for your search result. It will be displayed in your results even if it wasn't the search term because it is associated with it.

All in all, your search.php page should look like this:

```
get_header(); ?>
<div id="BodyWrap">
<div id="mainCont">
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<div id="mainCopy">

    <div id="content" class="narrowcolumn" role="main">

    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <h2 class="pagetitle">Search Results</h2>

        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
        </div>


        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div <?php post_class() ?>>
                <h3 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <small><?php the_time('l, F jS, Y') ?></small>

            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
        </div>

    <?php else : ?>

        <h2 class="center">No posts found. Try a different search?</h2>
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```